# ThreeJS/WebGL: Pass function into shader

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I have written a noise function outside of my shader that takes in a 3D coordinate (x,y,z) and outputs some noise value in [0, 1].  I'd like for this function to be available inside my vertex shader, so that I can animate vertex positions using the function.  Is this possible, or do I need to write my function inside the vertex shader itself.

Thanks

Comment: It will have to be defined in GLSL. But check this out https://github.com/unconed/shadergraph

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide your function inside the vertex shader itself but, vertex shaders are just strings so if you want to use the same function in more than one shader do some kind of strings substitution or search and replace or template etc.

Example:

```
const noiseSnippet = `
   vec3 noise(float v) {
      ...
   }
`;

const someVertexShaderSource = `
   ${noiseSnippet}

   varying vec2 vUv;

   void main() {
       vUv = uv;
       vec3 p = position + noise(position.x);
       vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(p, 1.0);
       gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
   }
`;
```

Working example:

```js
// from: https://gist.github.com/patriciogonzalezvivo/670c22f3966e662d2f83
const noiseSnippet = `
float mod289(float x){return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;}
vec4 mod289(vec4 x){return x - floor(x * (1.0 / 289.0)) * 289.0;}
vec4 perm(vec4 x){return mod289(((x * 34.0) + 1.0) * x);}

float noise(vec3 p){
    vec3 a = floor(p);
    vec3 d = p - a;
    d = d * d * (3.0 - 2.0 * d);

    vec4 b = a.xxyy + vec4(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    vec4 k1 = perm(b.xyxy);
    vec4 k2 = perm(k1.xyxy + b.zzww);

    vec4 c = k2 + a.zzzz;
    vec4 k3 = perm(c);
    vec4 k4 = perm(c + 1.0);

    vec4 o1 = fract(k3 * (1.0 / 41.0));
    vec4 o2 = fract(k4 * (1.0 / 41.0));

    vec4 o3 = o2 * d.z + o1 * (1.0 - d.z);
    vec2 o4 = o3.yw * d.x + o3.xz * (1.0 - d.x);

    return o4.y * d.y + o4.x * (1.0 - d.y);
}
`;

const vs = `
  ${noiseSnippet}

  uniform float time;

  void main() {
    float n = noise(vec3(position) + time) * 2. - 1.;
    vec3 p = position + vec3(0, n * .1, 0);
    vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(p, 1.0);
    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * mvPosition;
  }
`;
const fs = `
  precision mediump float; 
  void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1, 0, 0, 1);
  }
`;

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 1, 3000);
camera.position.z = 4;

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
const uniforms = {
  time: { value: 0, },
};
const material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
  uniforms: uniforms,
  vertexShader: vs,
  fragmentShader: fs,
  wireframe: true,
});
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(mesh);

renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);


function resizeCanvasToMatchDisplaySize(canvas) {
  const width = canvas.clientWidth;
  const height = canvas.clientHeight;
  if (canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height) {
    renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    camera.aspect = width / height;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }
}

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;  // convert to seconds
  uniforms.time.value = time * 4.;
  
  resizeCanvasToMatchDisplaySize(renderer.domElement);
  
  mesh.rotation.y = time;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vh; display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r83/three.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function must be part of the vertex shader source code. There's no way to "import" a function into a shader, e.g., as a parameter or by taking it from a different shader.

Comment: This is not entirely true. I think that Three itself can parse an import statement even though it wouldnt be your standard webgl/glsl feature. This is how the shaders are combined from the chunks i believe.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant from another compiled shader. #include is essentially string concatenation.